# As of or from difference

Tags: grammar, synonyms

How is it different 'as of ' from 'from' in this context

"EU businesses must acquaint themselves with the formalities and procedures for doing business with the United Kingdom as a third country **as of** 1 January 2021"

Can I say 'from' 1st January instead of 'as of' with no change in meaning??

Comment: "As of" means starting with that date.  "From" is ambiguous -- it could mean starting with the next day.

Answer (score -1):

Years and years ago, I learned from a very experienced solicitor:

> After December 31, 2020

is unambiguous and succinct.

From January 1, 2021

is succinct but ambiguous

On or after January 1, 2021

is unambiguous but not succinct.

That old man drove me berserk by marking up my drafts when I was under a deadline, but I learned a lot from him about careful drafting.